# Merging ui-grid data

Tags: angularjs

Having two UI-grid,

```
vm.grid.order , having val1 & val2
vm.grid.reorder , having val3 & val5 & val7
```

bind these two grid values to vm.order

```
vm.order = vm.grid.order;
vm.order.push(vm.grid.reorder)
```

It returns an array like this

```
  {
    [0]: "val1",
    [1]: "val2",
    [2]: ["val3", "val5", "val7"],
    etc
  }
```

How can I get it like this

```
 {
    [0]: "val1",
    [1]: "val2",
    [2]: "val3", 
    [3]: "val5", 
    [4]: "val7"
    etc
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

use the concat method:

```
vm.order = vm.grid.order.concat(vm.grid.reorder)
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat